# How to find the maximum subarray of size >= 2 for the given array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given an array and an integer k, find the maximum for each and every contiguous subarray of `size >=2`.

INPUT:

```
int[] array = new int[]{-5,-2,-3,-1,-1};  
int[] array1 = new int[]{5,2,3,-3,1,1};
```

OUTPUT:

```
-1,-1   //Since the maximum sum with maximum contiguous subarray can be of size 2 or greater than 2 and all are negative, so we taking the subarray  = -1 -1    
5,2,3  // Because we need to find the maximum sum and  maximum subarray with limitation that array can be >= 2
```

I have solved this but my solution is not working when all the integers are negative. Also, it is not working when input is -5,-2,-3,-3,1,1. The output should be 1 and 1 but it is coming as -3,-3,1 and 1.

I need an optimized solution. Please find my code below:

```
public class Pro {

    static int[] maxSubarray(int[] a) {

        int max_sum = a[0];
        int curr_sum = a[0];

        int max_start_index = 0;
        int startIndex = 0;
        int max_end_index = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (max_sum > curr_sum + a[i]) {
                startIndex = i-1;
                curr_sum = a[i];
            } else {
                curr_sum += a[i];
            }

            if (curr_sum > max_sum) {
                max_sum = curr_sum;
                max_start_index = startIndex;
                max_end_index = i;
            }
        }

        if (max_start_index <= max_end_index) {
            return Arrays.copyOfRange(a, max_start_index, max_end_index + 1);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = new int[]{-5,-2,-3,-1,-1};
        int[] array1 = new int[]{5,2,-3,1,1};
        int[] out = maxSubarray(array1);
        for(int a : out)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    }

}
```

There is one more code snippet which can be helpful. It finds the maximum subarray. See code below:

```
public int maxSubArray(int[] A) {
        int max = A[0];
        int[] sum = new int[A.length];
        sum[0] = A[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
            sum[i] = Math.max(A[i], sum[i - 1] + A[i]);
            max = Math.max(max, sum[i]);
        }

        return max;
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem, could you explain it a little more.

Comment: Like @nickn said, please explain the problem a bit more. Why does array 1 give 5,2,3 and not 1,1 as well? Your `subbarray >= 2` is the confusing part of your statement. Does it have to have a least 2 array entries?

I suspect the issue comes from here `curr_sum += a[i];` but we need more clarification. Like I said more examples of what should happen would help

Comment: added explanation . Please check

Comment: Fighting illiteracy - sentences end with "." .

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you are using is called Kardane's algorith and cannot be used when all the numbers are negative. At least one number has to be positive for the algorithm to work. To make it work for arrays with negative numbers but also at least one positive number, `curr_sum` should be set to 0 whenever you come across a negative number in your array. One way to achieve this is to use a custom max-function

```
private int max(int first, int second) {
     if (first < second) return first;
     else return second;
}
```

Replace:

```
if (max_sum > curr_sum + a[i]) {
       startIndex = i-1;
       curr_sum = a[i];
       } else {
          curr_sum += a[i];
       }
```

with:

```
curr_sum = max(curr_sum + a[i], 0); 
if (curr_sum == 0) startIndex = i + 1;
```

Full code:

```
   public int max(int[] a) {
    int max_sum = a[0];
    int curr_sum = a[0];
    int startIndex = 0;
    int max_start_index = 0;
    int max_end_index = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        max_sum = max(max_sum + a[i], 0);
        if (max_sum == 0) startIndex = i + 1;
        curr_sum = max(curr_sum, max_sum);
        if (curr_sum == max_sum) {
            max_start_index = startIndex;
            max_end_index = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Start index: " + max_start_index);
    System.out.println("End index: " + max_end_index);
    return curr_sum;
}
```

Input: `-5, -2, -3, -3, 1, 1`

Output:

`Start index: 4
End index: 5
2`

Comment: When i am giving this input = -5,-2,-3,-3,1,1 ...then the answer is -5 and -2 in your case which is not maximum. It should be 1 and 1

Comment: See my edit. startIndex needs to be set to i + 1 whenever a negative number is encountered, not i - 1.

Comment: I have seen your edit, When i am giving this input = -5,-2,-3,-3,1,1 ...then the answer is still -5 and -2 in your case which is not maximum. It should be 1 and 1 .. I have also made some changes in my question and added more explanation. See,if its helpful for you

Comment: Please run your code in IDE.. its still not showing the desired output for the same input